# Equivalent class for Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract in magento2

Tags: magento2, module, helper

Helpers in Magento2,

What is the equivalent class for the Magento 1 `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`

```
class Vendor_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is `Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`

Thus you can create your class like this:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Magento1 : Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract

Magento2 : \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
```

For example you can use like this in magento-2.

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

}
```